# Using a NFS for gcc, Apache, PHP, MySQL, glibc

Tags: mysql, php, nfs, gcc, apache-httpd

I have 7 SLES VM. I am compiling always the newest version of

1. `gcc` and all dependencies.
2. `Apache` and all dependencies.
3. `PHP` and all dependencies.
4. `MySQL` and all dependencies.
5. `glibc` and all dependencies.

In total this means I have to maintain about 20 different programs on **each of the 7 VM**.

**My question:**
I am just wondering if it is a good idea I create a NFS which I mount on each of the 7 VM and therefore I have to compile and maintain all these programs only once. I don't think the *lower* speed of the NFS does matter because the programs are loaded once into the cache when they are needed and kept in RAM as long they run. Each VM has enough RAM [>4 GB].

I guess that all of the 7 VM must have the same OS version.

Comment: Introduces a single point of failure (lose the NFS server or connectivity to it, lose functionality on all 7 SLES VMs).  Why not compile them once and `rsync` the compiled programs over to each of the 7 SLES VMs ?

Comment: @steve Good point. But when I lose the NFS server then also my own project won't work. This is for me not the problem. The NFS server is on the same host and therefore there is not really a reason why it should not be reachable. When, then the host has a general problem.

Comment: This is what packages are for.  if SLES 7 doesn't have new enough versions of the packages you want, build updated packages yourself (on your fastest machine), then install it on all VMs.  Or install a newer SLES (7 is **ancient**, 12 is current).

Comment: @cas I never mentioned I have SLES 7. I have 7 VM with SLES 11 SP2 and it is using very old versions. Updates are available only when you pay - take it times 7. Therefore I update all on my own and I do not depend on  distribution policies.

Comment: ah, sorry, i misread that as SLES 7, not as 7 x SLES.   BTW, if you don't want to pay for a commercial enterprise distro, then why use it?  There's **NO** good reason to use RHEL or SLES unless you want the support and updates (which you have to pay for).  Avoid your self-inflicted problems by using OpenSUSE instead.  Or better yet, Debian.  or Ubuntu.